# Why do I get "Cannot read property...of undefined with this object?

Tags: javascript, object, browser

Could someone help me figure out what the problem is. I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw_map' of undefined(…)" in browser when running the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

Maps = function(id, img_src, width, height) {
    var self = {
        id: id,
        img: new Image(),
        width: width,
        height: height
    }

    self.img.src = img_src;

    self.draw_map = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(self.img, 0, 0, self.img.width, self.img.height, 100, 100, self.img.width * 2, self.img.height * 2);
    }
}

function update_canvas() {

    current_map.draw_map();

}

///////////////////////////////////////////

// get context to draw on canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Load Image for map
var current_map = Maps("field", "img/dirt.jpeg", 120, 480);

// Drawing
setInterval(update_canvas, 500); 

}); // End of Document.ready
```

Comment: `var current_map = new Maps("field", "img/dirt.jpeg", 120, 480);`

Comment: I've tried adding new and I get "current_map.draw_map is not a function(…)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the function

```
Maps = function(...) { ... }
```

doesn't return self object.

Probably you want to use it as a construction function so change this line using new operator:

`var current_map = new Maps("field", "img/dirt.jpeg", 120, 480);`

Comment: This worked for me. i added 'code' return self; 'code' to the end of the function and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: without new operator he is creating object.so what is the use of `new` keyword in js

Comment: @Mahi the new is not enough, he need to replace self with this to make it work. Otherwise he just need to return self at the end of the function and use Maps as a normal function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code (with the HTML elements commented out). The problem was that you are not using the `this` reference inside the function constructor and then not using the `new` operator to create an instance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

Maps = function(id, img_src, width, height) {
    this.id = id;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.img = new Image() // replace with your Image
    this.img.src = img_src;
    var self = this; // Required for the draw_map function

    this.draw_map = function() {
      
      console.log("Draw image", self.img.width, self.img.height);
        // Uncomment in your code: ctx.drawImage(self.img, 0, 0,     self.img.width, self.img.height, 100, 100, self.img.width * 2, self.img.height * 2);
    }
}

function update_canvas() {

    current_map.draw_map();

}

///////////////////////////////////////////

// get context to draw on canvas. Uncomment
//var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
//var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Load Image for map
var current_map = new Maps("field", "img/dirt.jpeg", 120, 480);
// Drawing
setInterval(update_canvas, 500); 

}); // End of Document.ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```